# How to do this in functional way?

Tags: python, scala, functional-programming

Say, I have a `List[Byte]` and it's for represent a `List[String]`.

This `List[Byte]` 's first four elements can be converted to an `Int32`. this `Int` is the length of the string which follows the first four elements.

And then loop till there is no string to read.

I wrote a simple `Python` code, but still want to do this in functional way. and prefer to use `Scala`.

Here's my code.

```py
def _parse_type_string(raw: bytes):
    length = len(raw)
    result = []

    index = 0
    while index + 4 > length:
        read_length = int.from_bytes(raw[index: index + 4], 'little')
        if index + 4 + read_length > length:
            break
        content = raw[index + 4: index + 4 + read_length].decode('ascii')
        result.append(content)
        index = index + 4 + read_length
```

Comment: You typically don't get translations to other languages on this site. Try to write it in scala and ask when you have questions.

Comment: @JohnJoker don't take comments on SO to close. I believe mcsoini did not want to be rude. It just SO policy. I have upvoted your question to make this day a bit better for you

Answer (score 2):

I'd be tempted to `unfold()` the list of raw bytes.

```
val ss: List[String] =
  List.unfold(rawBytes){bs =>
    Option.when(bs.nonEmpty) {
      val len = 4 + bs.take(4).foldLeft(0)(_.<<(8) + _)
      (bs.slice(4, len).map(_.toChar).mkString, bs.drop(len))
    }
  }
```